# Unable to remove encryption

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, recovery-mode, factory-reset, twrp, encryption

I have a galaxy note 4 that isn't rooted but has TWRP 2.8.5 installed. I wanted to factory data reset the device, however, I was getting the error that it was unable to mount /data. I read on XDA that I had to format data. I clicked on format data and typed in yes.

I got the message "Formatting Data using make_ext4fs function. You may need to reboot recovery to be able to use /data again. Updating partition details ... done". I see the status as "Data Format Complete Successful".

I rebooted the device, and I know the OS loaded, but I was greeted with the error "Encryption failed, cannot decrypt your device storage. You need to reset your device to factory default settings". And a reset device button. I click on the reset device button, it boots me to recovery and runs a script and again reboots to the previous error.

I tried to factory data reset it now, although it showed as successful, I was directed to the same error. 
Can you please advise what should be done?

Thank you

Comment: You may want to flash a "Forced Encryption Disabler" package, which also disables DM-Verity (if present).

Comment: I get an error when trying to flash this - http://imgur.com/CNoX871 "error flashing zip"

Comment: I see people on XDA Developers [succeeded after flashing SuperSU](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s7/help/error-installing-verity-opt-encrypt-zip-t3436385). You can acquire SuperSU [here](http://www.supersu.com/download).

Comment: I don't think flashing SuperSU will help as I cannot access the GUI after booting. It immediately prompts me with the error as before.